# How to navigate to child component on form submission if function returns true? [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

I have a student-view component in which I have a form which on submission runs function searchStudent and checks if a student is present in students list. If student is present I want to go to the url = "student-view/{rollNo}". I managed to navigate to the url but the student-result component does not render. What is the correct way to acheive this?

my student-view.ts component -

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Student } from 'src/app/Student';
import { StudentDataTransferService } from 'src/app/student-data-transfer.service';
import { StudentResultComponent } from '../student-result/student-result.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student-view',
  templateUrl: './student-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student-view.component.css']
})
export class StudentViewComponent implements OnInit {

  name: string = ""
  rollno: number = 0
  
  studentList = this.studentDataTransferService.getData();

  constructor(private studentDataTransferService: StudentDataTransferService, private router: Router) {
    console.log(this.studentList)
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      
    }

  searchStudent(){
    for (let i=0; i< this.studentList.length; i++){
      if (this.rollno == this.studentList[i].rollNo){
        console.log(this.studentList[i])
        this.router.navigate(["student-view/" + this.rollno])
      }
    }
    console.log("false")
    return false
  }
  
}
```

my student-view.html component template -

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text-center my-5">
        <h4>Find Result</h4>
    </div>
    <form (ngSubmit)="searchStudent()">
    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col">
            <label for="rollno" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Roll No.</label>
            <input type="text" name="rollno" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="rollno">
        </div>
        <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" [(ngModel)]="name">
        </div>
        <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-dark" value="Clear">
        </div>
        <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

my app-routing-module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './Components/login-page/login-page.component';
import { StudentResultComponent } from './Components/student-result/student-result.component';
import { StudentViewComponent } from './Components/student-view/student-view.component';
import { TeacherViewComponent } from './Components/teacher-view/teacher-view.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "", component: LoginPageComponent},
  {path: "teacher-view", component: TeacherViewComponent},
  {path: "student-view", component: StudentViewComponent, children: [{
    path: ":rollNo", component: StudentResultComponent
  }]},
  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

my project structure -
[image: Project Structure]

**What I am trying to acheive -**
**I want to make student-result component student-view component's child and I want to navigate to student result on submission of form if student entered in form is present in students list.
I hardcoded it and it does not render my student-result component on form submission (just changes the url). What is the correct way to acheive this?**

Comment: if you are making student-result child component of student-view then there is no need to navigate. You can be  toggle the student-view (parent) to show or hide student-result(child) component

Comment: Yes, but the requirement says it needs to navigate to student-view/roll-no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child route expects there to be a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your student-view template. I don't know the whole plan for your app but I'm guessing you don't want ":rollNo" to be a child route. You probably want it to be something like this instead of it being a child route:

```
{ path: "student-view/:rollNo", component: StudentResultComponent }
```